# How can I include custom point symbols in legend

Tags: r, plot, legend

Consider the following data / plot, which works as I am only assigning numeric values to `pch`.

```
plot(1:20, col='blue', pch=20); 
points(2:22, col='red', pch='+', cex=2)
points(4:24, col='green', pch=15)

legend('bottomright',c('Blue','Red', 'Green'),   
       col=c("blue", "red", "green"), horiz=T, cex=0.8,
       pch=c(20,20,15), bg='white')
```

But when I include a character value, it still plots a legend, but uses the **wrong point types**.

```
legend('bottom',c('Blue','Red', 'Green'),   
       col=c("blue", "red", "green"), horiz=F, cex=0.8,
       pch=c(20,'+',20), bg='white')
```

And when using only character values, the legend is correct again:

```
legend('bottomleft',c('Blue','Red', 'Green'),   
       col=c("blue", "red", "green"), horiz=F, cex=0.8,
       pch=c('!','+','*'), bg='white')
```

The legend in the middle is the problem. *How can I plot the legend with correct point types?*

I know that i could use `pch=3` for a "+" symbol, but what if i'm trying to plot a "!" symbol instead?
[image: plot]

Comment: because you're passing a vector to `pch` and vectors must be of the same data type

Comment: If I use `pch=c('20','+','20')` it is also throwing the warning and not plotting it correctly, although the vector now contains only characters.

Comment: you need to look at `?points` to find the numeric equivalent of the '+' - see my answer below

Comment: Do you need something like `plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", ylim = c(1,12), xlim=c(1,12)); text(1:12, rep("!", 12))` ?

Comment: No, I was looking for a way to mix characters and point types in the legend. But Chris answer solved it already. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `?points` one can pass the ASCii code to the symbol you wish to plot.  For the + the ASCii code is 43.

```
plot(1:20, col='blue', pch=20); 
points(2:22, col='red', pch='+', cex=2)
points(4:24, col='green', pch=15)

legend('bottomright',c('Blue','Red', 'Green'),   
       col=c("blue", "red", "green"), horiz=T, cex=0.8,
       pch=c(20,43,15), bg='white')
```

The following are acceptable values for pch:

> NA_integer_: no symbol.
>   0:18: S-compatible vector symbols.
>   19:25: further R vector symbols.
>   26:31: unused (and ignored).
>   32:127: ASCII characters.
>   128:255 native characters only in a single-byte locale and for the
>   symbol font. (128:159 are only used on Windows.)

Answer (score 3):

You either pass in a numeric vector or the symbols you want to use as characters. You cannt mix the two as you are trying to do since a vector can only be of one data type - in your case it is coercing all the values in the vector to `character`.

The below is what you should be specifying:

```
legend('bottomright',c('Blue','Red', 'Green'),   
   col=c("blue", "red", "green"), horiz=T, cex=0.8,
   pch=list(20,3,15), bg='white')
```

EDIT: Since you want the `!` symbol specifically you would have to look for the pch value of that. In this case it is pch = 33

Comment: I edited the question. I know i could use `pch=3`, but what if I want to plot a "!" symbol instead?  Is that just not possible?

Comment: I see. As far as I'm aware that's not possible. You either pass a numeric vector or a vector of one-character symbols - doesn't look like you can mix the two EDIT: found the `!` symbol as pch=33

Comment: `utf8ToInt("!")` tells you it's 33.